# Pull pixmap image source from ui edit text in QT

Tags: qgis, qt, qt-designer

I'm putting together a custom form for QGIS identify using Qt Designer.
One attribute has a file name to the accompanying photo of the feature. I'd like to have the photo label in the form grab the file source data from the edit text box that shows the file name on load. Then if the file name is changed or added, the picture can also update.
More specifically, the edit text may show "001", though the file name may be "C:\Photos\IMG_001.jpg".
Can pixmap be set up in Qt Designer to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using QtDesigner only, but it is possible with a custom python init script accompanying your dialog.

For general information about how you would get started, I would recommend to check out this very explanatory [blog-post](http://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/).